# Context Dispose deve ser usado no ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dispose

No *Web Forms* sempre que montei algum tipo de *CRUD*, utilizava o `using` para fazer um implícito *Dispose()*.

```
public List<Produtos> Lista ()
{
    using (var ctx = new DbContext())
    {
        return ctx. Produtos.ToList();
    }
}
```

No ASP.net MVC isso é feito de que forma?

```
public ActionResult Lista ()
{
    DbContext ctx = new DbContext ();
    return View ( ctx. Produtos );
}
```

Comment: Da uma olhada nesse link e vê se te ajuda http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380019/asp-mvc-when-is-icontroller-dispose-called

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você até pode fazer da mesma forma, mas não é necessário. O processo executado é efêmero e haverá a liberação dos recursos após a sua conclusão, isso é garantido pelo *framework* então a primeira forma está correta.

Note que isso ocorre apenas pela natureza efêmera do seu funcionamento. Não haverá uma liberação manual. Se houver alguma razão para achar (provavelmente tem alguma coisa errada) que precisa liberar antes de tudo se concluir, então a segunda forma é mais interessante. Coloco isso mais por completeza de informação. Normalmente você deixará o EF cuidar disso pra você.

[Leia mais](http://blog.jongallant.com/2012/10/do-i-have-to-call-dispose-on-dbcontext.html) e ainda [aqui](http://mehdi.me/ambient-dbcontext-in-ef6/).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 2):

No MVC você pode utilizar assim, que é a forma que mais vejo em projetos CRUD

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    using (var db = new Contexto())
    {
        return View(db.Produtos.ToList());
    }
}
```

Lembrando que o ActionResult pode retornar somente `View()` sem nenhum objeto.

Embora tem projetos que já vi que o contexto de conexão fica fora das `Actions`  como uma variável do `controller`, porém vai de gosto e necessidades do projeto.